# How to redirect from observer after add to cart?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to add a button "**Direct Checkout**" on my product details page. On click, it will add product to cart and redirect to `checkout/onepage`.

By default on addtocart Magento's redirect to cart page.

I have added a hidden field on product page and adding value in it on click of Direct Checkout button using javascript. Then in observer checking that value and redirect to checkout.

I have implement the above logic in observer `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` but it is not redirecting to checkout page, instead it redirects to cart page.

My observer function is:

```
public function afterAddToCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $params = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParams();
    if(isset($params['dco']) && $params['dco'] == 1){
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl("checkout/onepage"));
    }
}
```

I suppose it is not working because after my redirect code, magento executes default addtocart code which redirects it to cart again.

Is there any way I can break and simply redirect to checkout page?

Answer (score 1):

I typically go with

```
protected function _redirectToUrl($url, $code = 302)  {

    Mage::app()->getResponse()
        ->setRedirect($url, $code)
        ->sendResponse();
    exit;
}
```

You might want a different observer however: `sales_quote_save_after`

Comment: There is no such event `sales_quote_save_after` in magento?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the answer form this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4053248/3018289

Here is a copy for quick access.

You could create an observer listening for the checkout_cart_add_product_complete event and in there you could do something like the following

```
  public function addToCartComplete(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    // Send the user to the Item added page
    $response = $observer->getResponse();
    $request = $observer->getRequest();
    $response->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'));
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNoCartRedirect(true);
}
```

Your config would look something like this

```
 <frontend>
    <events>
    <checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
      <observers>
        <packagename_modulename_observer>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>packagename_modulename/observer</class>
          <method>addToCartComplete</method>
        </packagename_modulename_observer>
      </observers>
      </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
   </events>
   </frontend>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it comes from the fact that you don't send the response. I use :

```
$response = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse();
$response->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl("checkout/onepage"));
$response->sendResponse();
```

It works fine with 1.8 but I imagine it will with 1.9

Comment: No, it's not working. It is still sending to cart page. I think it is the problem of observer data flow, after completing add to cart it comes to our observer, but after doing redirect it again go back to cart function and then redirects to cart. Somehow we might need to break the observer, so it shouldn't go back to add to cart function.

Comment: Strange, but when I add `die;` after your code, it works :-/ is it right approach? Should I add `die` or not?

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand the aim previously... You need to change your cart into a quote else it redirects automatically. You can have a look at http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-quote-order-invoice-workflow/ to find how to change the cart into a quote.